# Default keybindings for evaluating code?

Tags: key-bindings

As far as coding so far I have only used emacs for R (using ESS). Now I am trying it with js and may use it for more languages. I wonder if there are default keybindings for evaluating code? 
Using ESS I mostly use C-c to send a code block and C-Ret for sending the current line. Now looking at sites regarding js, people seem to use C-x C-r for region for example.
Is it wise to adhere to a "standard", or just set them up as you go?

Comment: Keys for "working with code" is too broad a question. Keys for *evaluating* code include `M-:`, `C-M-x`, and `C-x C-e` - see the manual.

Comment: Most major modes (e.g. python-mode, js-mode, matlab-mode) will already have pre-defined keys for this sort of activity.  One way to find out what those bindings are is to open a buffer in that major mode (ie open a javascript file) and then press `C-h m` to learn more about the major mode and its key bindings.

Comment: Thanks, looking at keybindings for js2-mode there does not seem to be one for sending the current line. Why not? Still possible to add?